# JavaScript in laravel-dompdf

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, highcharts, dompdf

I am using laravel-dompdf to generate a PDF with a summary of results, consisting of tables and a few images, nothing to spectacular. I would like to print highcharts in the generated PDF as well. So first, I want to try a simple javascript code to see if it was working... but it isn't. I have enabled the `"DOMPDF_ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT" => true`, but so far no luck yet. The simple code which I want to print:

```
<div>foo</div>
<span id="insertHere"></span>
<div>bar</div>

<script>
    var el = document.getElementById('insertHere');
    el.innerHTML = '<div>Print this after the script tag</div>';
</script>
```

This only prints the foo and bar.. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: I can't find any reliable information about this feature on the github repo. And I can't find any good library that seems to do what you want. The best shot I see would be to use a PHP library that generates charts in image format... 

If you really want to use HighChart, you'll need to find a library like PhantomJS that is capable of actually executing and rendering javascript code...

Comment: I was already scared I would get this answer :-(. Thank you!

Comment: Is the `<script>` tag on top level? If so, try to wrap it inside a `<div>`.

Comment: Interesting @simon, I enclosed the <script> tags with <div>'s, and now the output is: foo, bar, ';

Comment: Try adding `type="text/javascript"` to your `<script>` tag, maybe that helps. Otherwise I don't know. Seems that JS support is not that good at this time

Comment: I do not know of any PHP-based PDF renderers that also support JavaScript. You would want to use a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) (based on webkit).

Comment: Or if a browser-based renderer is not an option you could use the [HighCharts export module](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview). (Anyone have time to work up an actual answer from this suggestion?)

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you all for the comments. I have tried the answer of @pnsh and this worked. I am starting to think that dompdf can only handle simple javascript, and nothing like graphs. Unfortunately, but not the end of the world. I think that I will advise the user to save the HighChart through the export module and print the PDF and HighChart separately.

Comment: A little different approach, requires some coding, but it can solve the problem with rendering chart + summary. You can render the summary as svg elements, then the Highcharts exporting should be able to render it to pdf. From the official site http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/

Comment: That's an awesome idea! Hope I can get it to work. Thank you @morganfree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dompdf** (or more specifically Back-end that it uses for PDF rendering) doesn't really render javascript. What it does is - it parse everything inside `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag and adds it in the special section of the pdf file.

I'm not sure if this javascript is what you need, since you can work with the dom tree outside of the `<script>` tag. What you can do is write simple scenarios, for example like this one:

```
<div>foo</div>
    <span id="insertHere"></span>
<div>bar</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    app.alert({cMsg:"Message", cTitle: "Title"});
</script>
```

Try to open generated file and you will see alert.

Here more complete guide on what you can do inside javascript section: [Acrobat JavaScript Scripting Guide](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for you comment! I tried the code and this showed a message box. I am starting to think that it can only handle 'simple' javascript :-(